# How to perform a git merge in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins

When Jenkins builds a non-master git branch, I want to merge in master automatically at a specific point. I don't want to use the git plugin's auto merge feature.

However, I've added the stage:

```
stage('Merge master') {
  sh 'git merge master'
}
```

But I get an error:

```
merge: master - not something we can merge
```

Jenkins seems to be checking out my branch in a weird way that prevents me being able to then merge master. What do I need to do to merge master into my branch?

Answer (score 2):

When Jenkins cloned your repo, it didn't checkout a local `master` branch

The following script should allow you to test a merge of master.

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git checkout branch-name
git merge master
```

Comment: This is worth a try, but since apparently Jenkins doesn't see a remote ref for `master` (see comments on my answer), I suspect this won't be sufficient. It may be cloning with a refspec that doesn't include `master`, or it may not be cloning at all (but rather selectively fetching)

Comment: Yeah this didn't work either. I got an error: `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address. error: Could not fetch origin`

Comment: @jbrown your credentials may not be set up, as this is the stage where git wants to ask you "Username for 'https://github.com':" but, as it is running on Jenkins node, has no console to do it. You need to either use tokens or set up a private key on Jenkins node and add it to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is probably just setting its head to the remote branch reference rather than creating a local branch.

Before I get into how to get around this, have you considered what should happen if the merge runs into conflicts?  Because probably what *will* happen is that it will put your build server into an unexpected state that you'll have to manually clean up.  This is why it is not typical to do merges other than locally (and interactively).

---

**UPDATE** : The following is retained from my original answer for completeness, but did not work:

> If you want to try in spite of that, you might need to say something like
>
> ```
> git merge origin/master
> ```

So it seems that Jenkins may be doing one of three things:

It may be using a remote name other than `origin`.  If that's all it is, then Edmund Dipple's answer should help.

It may be doing its clone with options like `--single-branch`, or otherwise configuring the remote's refspec so that `master` is not fetched.  In that case you would have to either reconfigure the repo yourself, or include an explicit refspec to fetch.

It may not be cloning at all.  This is mostly similar to the second case as far as how you'd address it; I guess the main thing I'd add is that it's conceivable the remote isn't even configured.

So the next step in my mind would be to have your build script show the local repo's configuration (`git config -l`) looking for `remote` and `fetch` settings, and figure out next steps from there.

Comment: Yeah I want it to fail to flag up to developers when merge conflicts arise so they can fix them early. This only runs on non-stable, non-master branches.

Comment: I get practically the same error: `merge: origin/master - not something we can merge`

Comment: Well, this is quickly turning into a Jenkins question... Jenkins is either (a) using a remote name other than `origin`, or (b) cloning the repo in such a way that it only sees the ref for the branch it's building.  Will update with additional suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to accomplish this with just the Git Plugin. Under **Additional Behaviors**, there is an option to **Merge before build**. Furthermore, you may be able to piggyback off of this within a Pipeline script

Comment: "I don't want to use the git plugin's auto merge feature"